# What are the default Backbone events?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm being a little lazy here but are these (below) all the default Backbone events. Also and am I correct in saying that the events bubble so a collection will receive any events triggered by a model.

**Backbone Model events**
change
error
sync
destroy

**Collection events**
add
remove
sync
reset

Many thanks
Lazy Nick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Backbone website ( http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog ):

#### Catalog of Events

Here's a list of all of the built-in events that Backbone.js can fire. You're also free to trigger your own events on Models and Views as you see fit.

- **"add"** (model, collection, options) — when a model is added to a collection.
- **"remove"** (model, collection, options) — when a model is removed from a collection.
- **"update"** (collection, options) — single event triggered after any number of models have been added or removed from a collection.
- **"reset"** (collection, options) — when the collection's entire contents have been replaced.
- **"sort"** (collection, options) — when the collection has been re-sorted.
- **"change"** (model, options) — when a model's attributes have changed.
- **"change:[attribute]"** (model, value, options) — when a specific attribute has been updated.
- **"destroy"** (model, collection, options) — when a model is destroyed.
- **"request"** (model_or_collection, xhr, options) — when a model or collection has started a request to the server.
- **"sync"** (model_or_collection, resp, options) — when a model or collection has been successfully synced with the server.
- **"error"** (model_or_collection, resp, options) — when a model's or collection's request to the server has failed.
- **"invalid"** (model, error, options) — when a model's validation fails on the client.
- **"route:[name]"** (params) — Fired by the router when a specific route is matched.
- **"route"** (route, params) — Fired by the router when any route has been matched.
- **"route"** (router, route, params) — Fired by history when any route has been matched.
- **"all"** — this special event fires for any triggered event, passing the event name as the first argument.

As for event bubbling, generally yes. When a model event is triggered it usually bubbles up through the collection as well. I'm not 100% sure if this is the case 100% of the time, but it usually is at least for the built in events.

Comment: Ha! I've on the site every day and I'd never seen that. Thanks man.

Comment: np. it's buried wwwwaaaaaay down deep at the very bottom of the site, all the way passed the examples and everything else. not a very good place for it :P

Comment: It's not the case for the `sync` event for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays URL is different: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

### A list build-in Backbone.js events:

- "add" (model, collection, options) — when a model is added to a
  collection.
- "remove" (model, collection, options) — when a model is removed from a collection.
- "reset" (collection, options) — when the collection's entire contents have been replaced.
- "sort" (collection, options) — when the collection has been re-sorted.
- "change" (model, options) — when a model's attributes have changed.
- "change:[attribute]" (model, value, options) — when a specific attribute has been updated.
- "destroy" (model, collection, options) — when a model is destroyed.
- "request" (model_or_collection, xhr, options) — when a model or collection has started a request to the server.
- "sync" (model_or_collection, resp, options) — when a model or collection has been successfully synced with the server.
- "error" (model_or_collection, resp, options) — when model's or collection's request to remote server has failed.
- "invalid" (model, error, options) — when a model's validation fails on the client.
- "route:[name]" (params) — Fired by the router when a specific route is matched.
- "route" (route, params) — Fired by the router when any route has been matched.
- "route" (router, route, params) — Fired by history when any route has been matched.
- "all" — this special event fires for any triggered event, passing the event name as the first argument.